# (CAD) Inventor - Extrude rectangular pattern of circle sketches

Tags: cad, autodesk-inventor

[[image]

[image]

Hello, I try to extrude a lot of circle sketches but I can't select all of them and when I try, there is so many lags. Does someone has a solution ? I am sorry I'm a noob in CAD. Thank you so much ! :)

Comment: Perhaps you should extrude one of the circles and then pattern the extrusion?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help, actually, I was trying to extrude one of the circles and then pattern the extrusion, it didn't work because I used rectangular pattern in the tab "sketch" instead of the retangular pattern in the "3D model" tab.

Comment: Yes - better to pattern the feature than the sketch